# Are they the same meaning?

Tags: phrases, relative-clauses

In the following sentence, is the meaning of *the evidence to base policies on* the same as *the evidence on which policies base*?

> [...] but what they often lack is the evidence to base policies on.

If it is correct, can I paraphrase *the evidence on which policies base* with *the evidence which policies base on*?

In addition, can I use *as* or any preposition in this position? Could you help me clarify this?

Comment: Don't say "the below"; say "this".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence

```
But what they often lack is the evidence to base policies on.
```

is idiomatic and doesn't need re-phrasing. Though, to be grammatically perfect and perhaps a little old-fashioned, it should be:

```
But what they often lack is the evidence on which to base policies.
```

The two phrases

```
"the evidence on which policies base"
```

and

```
"the evidence which policies base on"
```

misuse the expression *base something on* which - as [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/base) explains - means **Use (something specified) as the foundation or starting point for something.**

So evidence may be used as the foundation or starting point for policies. Policies may be based on evidence.

Yes - your use of **as** is correct.

Comment: Thanks for your explain. So I can paraphrase this one as "the evidence on which policies were based", right?

Comment: @Huy-Nguyen Not really. If a group of politicians lacked the evidence on which to base their policies they can't have based their policies on that evidence because they didn't have the evidence. If they made policies then they weren't based on the evidence. What you can say is " the evidence on which the policies _should_ have been based' or 'the evidence on which the policies _could_ have been based".

Comment: Sorry, but after I read your answer, I really don't understand. It makes me a little nervous. The answer of Brixtonian is very clear and I instantly recognize my mistake of misusing the expression. It's probably because I'm not a native speaker and I couldn't understand deeply enough.

Comment: "The evidence on which policies were based" is perfect English but it is in the *past tense*. "They often lack**ed** the evidence on which policies **were** based" would be correct. But in the *present tense*: "They often **lack** the evidence on which to base policies" would be correct.

Comment: Yes, I got it. Thanks again :D